# Shadows doesn't looks properly with Touchables in react-native

Tags: css, react-native

## Describing Problem

I have a Component that have shadow and it looks like this image below :

[image: Minus button with shadow]

When i wrap it with a Touchable it becomes so ugly and it look like this image below :

[image]

As you can see it seems bounded by a square and it doesn't look well .

---

## My Code

```js
<TouchableOpacity>
  <View style={homeStyles.plusAndMinusButton}>
    <Text style={homeStyles.plusAndMinusButtonText}>+</Text>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

and also my styles look like this :

```js
  plusAndMinusButtonText: {
    color: '#888',
    fontSize: 28
  },
  plusAndMinusButton: {
    marginLeft: 20,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 50,
    height: 45,
    width: 45,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    shadowColor: "#84A4FF",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.2,
    shadowRadius: 10,
    elevation: 3,
  },
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem together ?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of the TouchableOpacity element, what you need to do is either give the TouchableOpacity style or remove it. If you decide to give style to the TouchableOpacity make sure to give it enought height so it doesn't interfere the shadow

Comment: I don't want to give too much height to it because it has limited space to extends.

Comment: Decrease the size of the buttons and give more size to the TouchableOpacity, that should do the trick. The reason this is happening is because TouchableOpacity does not reckognize the radius of the shadow as height

Comment: dude decreasing size of the button causes bad user experience so i can't but thanks for your help

Comment: UX is other aspect here, i'm telling you that the best solution is to give style to TouchableOpacity and give it a height larger than the plus button

Answer (score 0):

Make the `TouchableOpacity` with `style={{flex: 1}}`.

In need to make the screen layout as it will be able to spread as much he wants.

Comment: You need to have it's parent `flex` too, Somewhere your layout shrinks and goes over the shadow

Answer (score 0):

Add `backfaceVisibility: 'hidden'` to your `plusAndMinusButton` style. Now shadow will display around the box.